# Grails: Parsing existing spring bean XML

Tags: xml, spring, grails

I am using Grails to build a front-end web-app to write and read from an existing schema. The data within the database is a collection of Spring bean XML definitions. I will want to parse the XML, allow my user to edit any of the properties using a friendly GUI and then save the whole bean definition back to the database. Obviously I can use an XML parser to work out the properties and what can be set. My question is, is there a smarter way to dynamically work with the bean definitions in Groovy / Grails either with built-in functionality or a plugin or should I just go with treating it all as bog-standard XML?

I'm very interested in extensibility (easily being able to deal with new definition types), efficiency (speed of processing) and elegance.

Comment: is the xml format a requirement?

Comment: I have not control over the bean format I'm reading in- they belong to an older application written in Java using Spring 2. The beans are stored as XML in a database and I want to be able to parse them and edit them in Groovy. I saw that there is a BeanBuilder class but it seems to need the bean definitions before being able to parse the bean? I just want to read in a bean and be able   to treat it as an object. Is this possible without having the definition available?